# PFObject has no member username Swift 2.0

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am using this code here:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username != '"+userName+"'")
    var query = PFQuery(className: "_User", predicate: predicate)

    do {
     var objects = try query.findObjects()


    for object in objects {

        **self.resultsUsernameArray.append(object.username!!)**
        self.resultsProfileNameArray.append(object["profileName"] as! String)

        }


    } catch _ {
        //Error handling, if needed
    }


}
```

The line bolded gives me the error **'The value of PFObject has no member username'**. Is there something am I missing here?

Thanks, Brock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 self.resultsUsernameArray.append(object["username"] as! String)
```

or try:

```
 self.resultsUsernameArray.append(object.objectForKey("username") as! String)
```

Comment: Thanks! This seemed to fix the error, for now I guess, Cheers! :D

Comment: happy to help :) if it's correct could you mark it as the correct answer please?